# Allow directory access for certain IP's at Lighttpd

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd, access-control

I need to rewrite this rules (from apache's .htaccess):

```
<files "*.*">
Allow from 84.47.125.0/19 66.211.160.0/19 216.113.160.0/19
Deny from All
</files>
```

To lighttpd ones, to allow the access to my /pswd directory only for those IP's:

```
84.47.125.0/19, 66.211.160.0/19, 216.113.160.0/19
```

How can I do that in lighttpd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used lighttpd but I've found this on Google:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-restrict-or-deny-access-by-ip-address.html

It has an example for blocking access for 2 IPs and for blocking a single IP. It should be easily adaptable for you by doing this:

```
# vi /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

and then:

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "84.47.125.0/19|66.211.160.0/19|216.113.160.0/19" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/pswd/" {
      url.access-deny = ( "" )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't seems like its working because when I use:
`"84.47.125.0/19|66.211.160.0/19|216.113.160.0/19"`
Those IP's (and even me, can't access folder /ipn/).

Comment: Just replace !~ with =~ in the first line